# Showing certain days as possible delivery days

Tags: php

I have possible delivery dates for an order form

```
$daysOff = ['Sat', 'Sun'];
for ($days = 1; $days <= 7; $days++) {
    $day = date("D", strtotime("today + $days day"));
    if (!in_array($day, $daysOff)) {
        $daysOnRearranged[] = date("D", strtotime("today + $days day"));
    }
}
```

This shows the next 5 days corrects

> Wed, Thurs, Fri, Mon, Tue

The last day tuesday, is showing today (4th), instead of 11th. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean it's showing the 4th? This just deals with the day names, not the dates.

Comment: It's showing the days of the week and dates. But it's showing the last day which should be next tuesday, as today.

Comment: 4th is most likely the array index, not the date.

Comment: There is no **date** but days, as stated @iainn. tuesday is 4th maybe because it's the 5th (index 4) element of the array.

Comment: I guess the problem is not in this part of the code? As far as I can see the output stored in `$daysOnRearranged` is just a day name and not it's number in-the-month?

Comment: Your code isn't "showing" anything, there's no output at all. All you're doing is building an array of day names.

Comment: The code works fine https://3v4l.org/VnFts

Comment: did you mean that you are facing sorting issue for the days ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy Yes. I need the last day Tuesday to be the 11th not the 4th,

Comment: really your question did show your problem, explain more it with example, what you want as a output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should display available dates like this:

```
  $daysOff = ['Sat', 'Sun'];
    for ($days = 1; $days <= 7; $days++) {
        $day = date("D", strtotime("today + $days day"));
        if (!in_array($day, $daysOff)) {
            $daysOnRearranged[] = date("D, j M", strtotime("today + $days day"));
        }
    }

print_r($daysOnRearranged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what should be done. Your question is not appropriate but answered.

```
$daysOff = ['Sat', 'Sun'];

        for ($days = 1; $days <= 7; $days++) {
          $day = date("D", strtotime("today + $days day"));
          $date = date('d', strtotime("today + $days day"));
          if (!in_array($day, $daysOff)) {
            $daysOnRearranged[$date] = date("D", strtotime("today + $days day"));
          }
        }
print_r($daysOnRearranged);
```